# depolying system contracts for new evm blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, geth-debugging

i was trying to fork a dpos evm blockchain , how to deploy system contracts for dpos and slash and get the "code" data  in genesis file as below ?

"alloc": {
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001000": {
"balance": "0x0",
"code": "0x6080604052600436106104525760003560......6f6c63430008110033"
},

"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001001": {
"balance": "0x0",
"code": "0x6080604050..........a45f4a64736f6c63430008110033"
},

Answer (score 0):

In the `code` part, you need to provide the bytecode of your contract.

In general, it goes something like this:

1. Prepare a contract in Solidity.
2. Compile the contract (eg using solc, remix, etc).
3. Copy the compiled bytecode and put it in the genesis.json file.
4. Then just initialize your chain with eg `geth init genesis.json`.

This will constitute the system contract "deployment" at genesis.

For a live example, have a look at Holesky testnet deposit contract: [0x4242424242424242424242424242424242424242](https://holesky.etherscan.io/address/0x4242424242424242424242424242424242424242)

Here's the respective part and the bytecode in the [Holesky genesis.json](https://github.com/eth-clients/holesky/blob/bb3dd03caea2bb01f1ebee48971791337aed522c/custom_config_data/genesis.json#L788).